# Referencing .net Core dll with external dependencies from .net Framework

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-framework-version

I have created a WinForms application that handles signaling between servers and clients using a custom protocol, TCP Sockets, and WebSockets (C#) in .NET Framework.
I created a .net Core 3.1 DLL which handles events from a VoIP server. The DLL has to be in .net Core because it relies on commercial DLLs which are provided as part of the VoIP SDK.
Packaging the DLL as NuGet multi-platform (.netcore 3.1 and net framework 4.62) partially solved the problem of referencing the DLL from the WinForms application. Since my .net Core DLL relies on two other .net core DLLs fails miserably to load with the following message:

> System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> XXXXXXXXXXX, Version=16.6.103.7338, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made
> to load a program with an incorrect format.'

Is there any way to wrap the two offending DLLs for use in .NET framework or re-implementing everything in .Net Core is the only way to go? Note that the offending DLLs are used as references to the original .net Core DLL.

Comment: With new versions of VS you can target Net or Core.  What version of VS are you using?

Comment: @jdweng I'm using VS 2019.

Comment: You would need to recompile the two projects and target Core.

Answer (score 0):

Re-implementing everything in .Net Core is one approach. It is not advisable to mix .net framework assemblies with .net core assemblies. Unless the commercial DLLs which are provided as part of the VoIP SDK target .net standard.

Another approach is to re-target the WinForms to .net core, which is possible since  .net core 3.0